# WebClient request timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I'm trying to return some html from a url via the WebClient class:

```
Response.Write(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.partnersite.com/html/"));
```

Whenever this code runs I get a timeout.

> The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.

If I browse directly to "http://www.partnersite.com/html/" I get an immediate response.

The timeout only seems to happen with this particular website, if I make a request to another site eg.

```
    WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.google.com"));
```

I'm instantly returned the html.

Is this simply a case of something going on at the partner site which means it's not responding? Or is there something else I can try before making that call?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the site accessible from Internet Explorer?

If not and if the site is in the same network, check whether you have bypassed the proxy for the site from the Internet Explorer options.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Anil. The site is accessible in IE as it is when browsing directly to it in any browser. The site that I'm requesting is on a completely different network.

Comment: Instead of using the DownloadString method, try using the DownloadFileAsync method and check whether you are receiving the data.